# COUNTIF how many times a value appears in a column, depending the content of a cells value

Tags: excel

i am trying this =COUNTIF(M1:M1000001;" * A1 * ") but is not working.

I want to count how many times the column dispays the content of the cell A1. Note that the content of the cell will appear as a content 
example:

0 A     M 
1 la    trala 
2  0    sela 
3  0    copy 
by these data, the result must be that the content of the cell A1 is appearing 2 times in the M column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using quotes, you are taking the literal "A1", so that `COUNTIF` is looking for " A1 " in your cells. What you probably wanted is this:

```
=COUNTIF(M1:M1000001;"*"&A1&"*")
```

When you put A1 outside the quotes, excel will refer to the cell A1. But then, you need to concatenate this result with the asterisks so you can search through the whole text of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
=COUNTIF($M$1:$M$100,"*"&A1&"*")
```